# Why does curl command take urls with parameters as input

Tags: wget, curl

I know both `wget` and `curl`. Being curious I read a little about [their differences](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html).

I recently tried to use `curl` with an url who has parameters and it turns out curl strips down the parameters from the url. The consequence is :  I don't get the page I requested.

So my question was, why does the curl command do that ?

Edit :

I tried following

```
# bare
$ curl -s http://tag.mobitrans.fr/horaires/index.asp?rub_code=23&lign_id=4&sens=2

# double quotes
$ curl -s "http://tag.mobitrans.fr/horaires/index.asp?rub_code=23&lign_id=4&sens=2"

# single quotes
$ curl -s 'http://tag.mobitrans.fr/horaires/index.asp?rub_code=23&lign_id=4&sens=2'

# escaping special chars
$ curl -s http://tag.mobitrans.fr/horaires/index.asp?rub_code=23\&lign_id=4\&sens=2
```

FWIW : `curl 7.34.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0) libcurl/7.34.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.26`

Comment: The "bare" case is irrelevant; the shell is interpreting the `&` character and not passing it on to `curl`. The others are problematic, but can be reduced to the case with single quotes. I suggest removing all but the single-quote case from your question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please post the command you used? It's likely you just needed to escape the URL because it had special characters to the shell such as apersands (`&`).

#### Example

```
$ curl http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dnmIG9/www.google.com
bash: !/dnmIG9/www.google.com: event not found
```

However if I put the URL in single quotes:

```
$ curl 'http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dnmIG9/www.google.com' |& head -10
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Use this free Website Speed Test to analyze the load speed of your websites, and learn how to make them faster.">
    <!-- Google PlusOne -->
```

#### Other issues

Sometimes you need to have cookies local or you need to be a certain type of browser or even have to appear to be coming from a particular URL within the site. In those instances you can often times finagle your way around them using additional switches to `curl`. The same can be done with `wget` too, by the way.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - yes that looks to be the exact issue I'm describing. Put the URLs in single quotes 'URL'.

Comment: See my 3rd try.  I'm not getting what I expected.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - Can you give us the error message that you're getting with the single quotes?

Comment: Hummm you seems to be right, it's seems to be a cookies issue. Without the quotes I get 3 process, with them I only get one.